# How to show color map of a value sum rather than average in plotly sunburst

Tags: python, plotly, sunburst-diagram

I have a graph that looks like this:

[image]

As per plotly's documentation:

*If a color argument is passed, the color of a node is computed as the average of the color values of its children, weighted by their values.*

I would like tha color map max value to be the `money_generated_sum`, which is not a column in my `df` but something that plotly generates itself. The column I use is `money_generated`.

The `df` follows this structure:

```
category      new      money_generated
dog           False    500
cat           True     800
cat           False    70
dog           False    5000
dog           True     300
```

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['category','new'], 
                      values='money_generated',
                      color = 'money_generated')
fig.show()
```

Is it possible to change how the color map values in plotly sunburst chart?

Comment: Can we see what `df` looks like to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @DerekO, added example `df`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible bit a bit hacky. There is probably a better method in which you change the values directly in the fig object but this method works for me:

```
d=fig.to_dict()
for trace in d['data']:
    trace['marker']['colors']=trace['values']

plotly.offline.plot(d, validate=False)
```

The for loop over the values in 'data' is only neccesary if you have multiple sunbursts in the same figure.

Answer (score 0):

How about you edit your dataset by grouping the variables and then finding the sum but save this in a separate dataset so you still have the original dataset intact;

```
df_1 = df.groupby(['cateogry', 'new']).sum().reset_index()
```

This will sum all the numerical columns (In your case, the money_generated column)
Then;

```
fig = px.sunburst(df_1, path=['category','new'], 
                  values='money_generated',
                  color = 'money_generated')
fig.show()
```

This should do the trick. It worked for me when I was working on other datasets, so hope this helps!